# C Language Pointer Memory?

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory

```
int num = 78;
int *p;

int array[SIZE] = {0,1,2,3,4};
char c[SIZE] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};

p = array[3];
*p = (int) *c;
p++;
array[4] = num;
p++;
p = c;
p++;
```

I'm trying to figure out the memory behind this above code. I understand that the pointer p initially points to the 3rd element of the array(which is 3). I have no idea what the next line *p = (int) *c; means. Can anyone please explain that line of code??

Edit:
After the p is incremented as such can anyone explain what it would be pointing to?

Comment: That will crash.  You want `p = &array[3];` or `p = array + 3;`.

Comment: [Find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read the chapters on arrays and pointers.

Comment: "I understand that the pointer p initially points to the 3rd element of the array". No. Your attempt to assign a value to `p` is simply invalid.

Answer (score 0):

`*p = (int) *c;`

`*c` means that you take the value at the address of c

`(int)` casts it to an int

`*p=` writes to the address `p` points to

So if you fix what droppy said, there will be the numerical value of `c[0]` in the 3rd part of `array`

so it would be `1,2,65,4,5`

Comment: "the address of `p`" is `&p`. You mean "to the address `p` points to". That is basic stuff one finds in any tutorial. The cast is problematic and a properly augmented compiler should actually warn about that assignment. Note: use markdown consistently.

Comment: @Olaf I'm sry, thats what I meant... Just formulated it wrong

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use 'p = &array[3];'. The pointer will then point to the third element of the array i.e. 'C'
2. `*p = (int) *c;`

`c[size]` is an array. `c` is the base pointer of the array. so `*c` is the value at the base pointer which is `'A'`. This statement will put `'A'` in the third element of the array. So the array now contains `A, B, A, D, E`

Answer (score 0):

```
p = array[3]; // int * = int
```

is an error; the types don't match, and the compiler will yell at you for it.  The type of `p` is `int *`, and the type of `array[3]` is `int`.

There are two ways to fix this, depending on what you want to do.  If you want to set `p` to *point* to `array[3]` (which is what you want to do in this case), you would write

```
p = &array[3]; // int * = int *
```

If you want to write the *value* of `array[3]` to the object that `p` points to (which is *not* what you want to do in this case, since `p` isn't pointing anywhere valid yet), you would write

```
*p = array[3]; // int = int
```

In this case, we want to set `p` to point to `array[3]`, so we use the first statement.  After doing that, the following are true:

```
 p == &array[3]          // int *
*p ==  array[3] == 2     // int
```

Now we have the statement

```
*p = (int) *c;
```

is saying "take the value of the `char` object that `c` points to, convert it to an `int` value<sup>1</sup>, and assign the result to the object that `p` points to."

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize an array of `char` in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

The *expression* `c` has type "5-element array of `char`".  Since it is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it is converted to an expression of type `char *`, and the value of the expression is the address of the first element in the array, `c[0]`.  Thus:

```
 c == &c[0]                         // char *
*c ==  c[0] == 'A' == 65 (ASCII)    // char
```

Taking all that together, that means

```
*p = (int) *c;
```

is another way of writing

```
*p = (int) c[0];
```

which is another way of writing

```
array[3] = (int) c[0];
```

which is another way of writing

```
array[3] = (int) 'A';
```

which is another way of writing

```
array[3] = 65;
```

---

1. `(int)` is a *cast expression*; it means that the value following it should be treated as type `int`.